# How to find cardinality of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How to find cardinality of a set of this type :

[image]

I know that if there were just integers as elements, that would be the number of elements, bu I'm not sure about this situation

Comment: The first step to answering any question is being able to read it.  Can you understand what the set $A$ is?  In other words given a number like $2$, can you decide whether it belongs to $A$?  If so then you should be able to make a list of all the numbers you think belong to $A$, and make that your starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question boils down to, how many integer roots does the polynomial $2x^5+3x^4$ have? It has a quadruple root at $x=0$, which leaves us with $2x+3=0$, which has no integer solutions. Thus, $A=\{0\}$, and $|A|=1$.